# Binding String List to ComboBox

Tags: c#

I am binding a `List<String>` to a ComboBox. I wrote this in two ways. The first way, the output of ComboBox was empty. Where i was wrong? please help me.
this is my code:

```
public class MaritalStatusComboBox:ComboBox
{
   public MaritalStatusComboBox()
    {       
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = new List<string> {"Single","Married" };

    }
}
```

and The Second way :

```
public class MaritalStatusComboBox:ComboBox
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>() { "Single", "Married" };
    public MaritalStatusComboBox()
    {
        this.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string str in list)
        {
            this.Items.Add(str);
        }

    }
}
```

output of ComboBox include of it:
Single,
Married,
**Collection**
Why does Collection appear in my ComboBox?

Comment: I think you add collection somewhere else, maybe you already did it in designer. I think the first example should read this.DataSource = new List<string>() { "Single", "Married" };

Answer (score 0):

In this first method, you didn't connect the DataSource:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = new List<string> { "Single", "Married" };
this.DataSource = bs;
```

The second method worked.  The posted code does not show the word "Collection".

Comment: i wrote "this.DataSource = bs;" but i has this error:  Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Comment: @johny Once you set the DataSource, you can't add items to via the `Items.Add(...)` method.  You would have to add them items to the DataSource.